# Simple transparent flash video?

Tags: adobe-flash

It's pretty basic, but I am having hard time with this.

I have created a simple line animation using Flash. This line should be imported to `iMovie` and appear above real objects with a **transparent background** so that you see only the line animated.

The thing is that Flash does not give me the option to get a transparent movie.

Is my only option is to create a png sequence then use other program to animate it?

Answer (score 0):

Export Video with ignore stage color checked off

[image]